# 80% exceedance rainfall calculation

Tags: probability

During crop-water requirement calculation, 80% exceedance value of precipitation is required. I calculate these values with usual statistical method (e.g. 80% exc. value = mean -0.8418 x Std deviation), wherein past historical data are required, and it is a bit more manual and tedious. Can it be estimated from Best, High and Low estimate, standard error and bias?

Comment: This would appear to be a question about some particular software or database, it doesn't appear to be a math problem.

Comment: The software gives best, high and low estimates, standard error and bias.